# signed-in User can't seem to be signed-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rspec, capybara

I used the M. Hartl Rails Tutorial to create my app. So I have a `User` model, and all `current_user` and `signed_in_user` methods.

I want to make the following test pass :

```
describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
  before do
    be_signed_in_as FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    patch user_path(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
  end
  specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
end
```

But the test fails :

```
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>.
   Expected "http://www.example.com/" to be === "http://www.example.com/signin".
```

So here is a part of the **User controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

      .
      .
      .
      .
  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless !current_user.nil?
        store_url
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: t('sign.in.please')
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

If I remove the `before_create :signed_in_user...` line, the test pass.
But why is that ? The `be_signed_in_as` spec method is working in all the others test (~ 1k) so the reason must lie within the `specify { expect(response)` thing.

Comment: `unless !current_user.nil?` this pretty much the worst logic you could write in this case. is that supposed to mean `if current_user.nil?` or `unless current_user.present?` ? nevertheless, i assume that the patch request does not send the session cookies to your application, so no `current_user`

Comment: And how can I simulate the session cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

Your test is going to a `user_path` for a different user than you're logging in as, so you're getting redirected to the root by your `correct_user` filter. You need to save the user that you're logging in as and use that for your `user_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`, you're creating an additional user. The code you list is creating two separate user records in the database. So unless you're intending on creating two different users for this test, you should probably have a line before the `before` block like:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

Then just refer to `user` everywhere you want the one user record.